# trigger of loading recaptcha library only when user interacts but not getting the value in hidden input field

Tags: javascript, laravel

As we all know that page speed plays an important role in SEO and whenever you tried to implement google Recaptcha v3 it will slow your site a lot. that's why I decided to trigger the loading/execution/running of the reCaptcha library only when the user interacts with the input form(s). This is, actually, quite possible ..
here is my code and website [igsavers](https://igsavers.com)...

```
    <form method="post" action="/video">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="control is-loading">
        <input name="instauser" id="author" class="input is-rounded is-focused is-medium" type="text" placeholder="https://instagram.com/p/41SW_pmmq4/">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="">
    <div class="control has-text-centered">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="button is-danger is-active is-medium">Download &nbsp
            <img src="{{ asset('svg/downloads.svg') }}" width="25px" alt="Instagram video download" />
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // trigger loading api.js (recaptcha.js) script
        var reCaptchaFocus = function() {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy';
        head.appendChild(script);

        // remove focus to avoid js error:
        // Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element at Object.kh
        document.getElementById('author').removeEventListener('focus', reCaptchaFocus);
        };
        // add initial event listener to our basic HTML form
        document.getElementById('author').addEventListener('focus', reCaptchaFocus, false);
    </script>
```

this code is working well but the problem is that hidden input type `g-recaptcha-response` value will remain empty. here is my code of adding value in this field

```
<script>grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
       document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
    });
});</script>
```

help me to figure out what I change in the code to load the value in hidden input type.

Comment: Why are you not adding the `grecaptcha.ready()` event into the `reCaptchaFocus()` function? You should add this event  right after `head.appendChild(script);`

Comment: @AlonEitan any example will greatly appreciated bro.. i tried that but ran into erros

Comment: yes, it's working ... it's very silly mistake :-(

Comment: I posted an answer explaining what you need to change

Comment: @AlonEitan this script is working but i am facing problem at first click on input form it loads the lib file and after 2nd 3rd click it loads the value ... please help me i need to solve this issue ... visit on my site and submit anything

Comment: After this line: `head.appendChild(script);` you have this line `});` - it causing a syntax error

Comment: You need to copy this line `grecaptcha.ready(function() {` and the next 3 lines **before** the `});` that I mentioned in my last comment

Comment: @AlonEitan i am exactly doing that you have suggested me ... just see my source code once and test it . https://igsavers.com

Comment: Try changing the path to `script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy';` and change `grecaptcha.ready(function() { .... });` to `var onloadCallback = function() { .... };` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render)

Comment: @AlonEitan i already tried that ... according to me ... on first click on input field it loads the lib file and tried to load the value before completing the loading of lib file and when users again click on input field it loads value because lib file is already loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205312/discussion-between-nalin-nishant-and-alon-eitan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `grecaptcha.ready` event without fist loading the recaptcha script. You should remove

```
<script>grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
       document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
    });
});</script>
```

And place it after you loaded the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var reCaptchaFocus = function() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy';
    head.appendChild(script);

    var recaptchaInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if( !window.grecaptcha || !window.grecaptcha.execute ) { return; }

        clearInterval( recaptchaInterval );

        grecaptcha.execute('6LdvEswUAAAAADNVG2ng4ZIfA4mfKUJiuLmLgnUy', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
            document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
        });
    }, 100 );
    document.getElementById('author').removeEventListener('focus', reCaptchaFocus);
};
document.getElementById('author').addEventListener('focus', reCaptchaFocus, false);
</script>
```